# JS causing window size to be bigger than necessary - Dropdown bug

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using Foundation CSS and I recently added a dropdown. You'll have to login (username: stackoverflow password: testtest) there http://broadcasted.tv/ to see it.

Basically, the page on the right is longer than it should (when logged in) but gets to the right size when the dropdown is clicked on. Anyone knows why that's happening ?

Edit: Just noticed it can be fixed by deactivating .f-dropdown {position:absolute}...

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
 top: -99999px;
```

to

```
 left: -99999px;
```

Don't know if that'll help anyone but it might...